# mongodb findAndUpdate : get original document value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We are trying to implement versioning of documents in mongodb for our project using nodejs. For this, while we perform the **findOneAndUpdate** command we want to find the difference between the existing document and the new values being updated into it. The **returnNewDocument** parameter returns the new document after updating is there any way to get the base document ( the one before update is performed). Or is there any better way to perform mongodb document versioning?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: You cxan use mongoose?

Comment: @ŞükSefHam does moongose support document versioning by default? or do we have to manage it ourself?

Comment: You must install mongoose module